# How to add google webmaster verification html file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-search-console

I am new with google webmaster tools.
While i adding a property in webmaster it provides me a **html** file for verification and also they instructed to upload the file in the server . I done that but the verification fails. 
I done the website using codeigniter , i want to know that is there any specific location tho upload the file while using the framework.

Comment: Please download the verification file provided on the Verification page of Search Console and upload it to public_html

Comment: @Joby Mathews put provided file in root directory of Codeigniter where index.php and also put **robots.txt** which allow **Googlebot** to read your website. for more information about robots.txt http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: i uploaded it in public_html but it shows error

Answer (score 0):

If you have a layout view page which gets loaded each time place it in the head.

ex. mine is located in views/template/layout.php

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!google site verification -->
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="" />
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
  <!-- Google Analytics -->
  <script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', '', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>
 </head>
```